# Splitting a sequence of binary digits based on inputs in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of binary digits that represent an address. I want to now segregate this address into 3 parts or arrays that are `tag`, `index` and `offset` and the number of bits for each of these three are determined by the user.
For better clarity, this is the code:

```
char* bin_val_addr;
while(fscanf(FP, "%s %lx", str, &addr) != EOF)
{

    bin_val_addr = long_to_binary(addr);

    char* array_Tag = malloc(no_Tag_bits * sizeof(char*));
    char* array_Index = malloc(no_Index_bits * sizeof(char*));
    memcpy(array_Tag, bin_val_addr, no_Tag_bits * sizeof(char*));
    memcpy(array_Index, bin_val_addr, no_Index_bits * sizeof(char*));
    printf("TAG array is: %s\n", array_Tag);
    printf("INDEX array is: %s\n", array_Index);


}
```

And the function long_to_binary is as follows:

```
char* long_to_binary(unsigned long k)
{
        static char c[65];
        c[0] = '\0';

        unsigned long val;
        for (val = 1UL << (sizeof(unsigned long)*8-1); val > 0; val >>= 1) 
        {        
            strcat(c, ((k & val) == val) ? "1" : "0");
        }
        return c;
}
```

I looked up ways to split arrays and found that `memcpy` can be used but I am going wrong somewhere while implementing this. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: If you want to store, for example, 1010 in a string then that string will need to be at least 5 characters in length (4 to hold 1010 and 1 to hold the string's null terminator). Your code is incorrectly allocating 4 char pointers, when it should allocate 5 chars. There are other problems here too, for example the way you are returning 'c' from the long_to_binary() function needs to change.

Comment: okay so I'd have to change the `sizeof(char*)` statement right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to allocate a string that can hold N characters then you need to malloc(N+1), rather than malloc(N * sizeof(char *)).

Comment: And why is the way I return c wrong?

Comment: Ah, it's static. Did not notice that earlier. It's OK in that case (I'm not a big fan but it will work).

Comment: Well that didn't work. The array size is still the same as the original one

Comment: I'd recommend a few things: print the output of long_to_binary() to make sure it's' correct; print the values of no_xxx_bits similarly, use calloc() rather than malloc(); fix the memcpy to array_Index (it should not start from bin_val_addr).

Answer (score 0):

If `bin_val_addr` contains the sequence of `1s` and `0s` in the order `tag`, `index` and `offset`, then the following copies from the **beginning** of `bin_val_addr` for both `array_Tag` and `array_Index`, e.g.

```
    memcpy(array_Tag, bin_val_addr, no_Tag_bits * sizeof(char*));
    memcpy(array_Index, bin_val_addr, no_Index_bits * sizeof(char*));
```

If `array_Index` begins **after** `array_Tag` in `bin_val_addr`, then you would need to offset your source for `array_Index` by `no_Tag_bits`.

(and note you are mixing bits and bytes (you have characters `'1'` and `'0'` not bits). So, unless you need **8-bytes** per-character, `sizeof(char*)` should be `sizeof(char)` -- which is always `1` and should be eliminated from your allocations)

For example, allocating to hold the *characters* specified in each array (`+1` for the *nul-terminating* character), you could do:

```
    char *array_Tag = malloc(no_Tag_bits + 1);
    char *array_Index = malloc(no_Index_bits + 1);
```

and you must validate each allocation, because `malloc` can and will fail returning `NULL` on memory exhaustion, e.g.

```
    if (!array_Tag) {
        perror ("malloc-array_Tag");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Putting those pieces together and *nul-terminating* each string, you would have:

```
    memcpy (array_Tag, bin_val_addr, no_Tag_bits);
    array_Tag[no_Tag_bits] = 0;
    memcpy (array_Index, bin_val_addr + no_Tag_bits, no_Index_bits);
    array_Index[no_Index_bits] = 0;
```

Which would now allow you to output the arrays as *strings*:

```
    printf ("TAG array is: %s\n", array_Tag);
    printf ("INDEX array is: %s\n", array_Index);
```

Lastly, your use of `fscanf` invites *Undefined Behavior* on a *matching* or *input* failure where less that the total number of conversions specified takes place. Instead of checking against `EOF`, you should validate with the number of conversions specified actually occurred, e.g.

```
while (fscanf (FP, "%s %lx", str, &addr) == 2)
```

After making those changes, and presuming your `long_to_binary` is working as you intend, let me know if you have further questions.